# Laravel 5: Access attribute from other Model

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to use a whereBetween inside a whereHas but my whereBetween is not working because inside whereHas is not getting my turned attribute from my User Model:

**This is my query**

```
DB::raw("*, ( 
        3959 * acos( 
        cos(radians(?)) 
        * cos(radians(latitude))
        * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(?)) 
        + sin(radians(?)) 
        * sin(radians(latitude)))
    ) AS distance"))
->having('distance', '<', $distance)
->orderBy("distance")
->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat])
->whereHas('user', function($q) {
    $q->whereBetween('date_of_birth',array(Input::get('age_from'),Input::get('age_to')))
      ->where('gender',Input::get('gender'))
      ->where('title','LIKE','%'.Input::get('title').'%');
})
->with('user')
->get();
```

**User Model**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    public function getDateOfBirthAttribute()
    {
        $ca = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->attributes['date_of_birth']);

        return $ca->diffInYears();
    }

}
```

**Location Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Location extends Model {

    protected $table = 'locations';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

Date of birth field in the query is not getting the turned value to years instead is getting the value in the date format like YYYY-MM-DD as in the table is.

Comment: What's the DOB field look like then?

Comment: The type of DOB in the database is 'date' and in the query is taken the date format not the number of years of the user model. So the query is not sending any error but is comparing the the age_from and the age_to (numbers) with a YYYY-DD-MM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but was not necessary to access to the attribute from other model, just use this whereBetween.

```
$q->whereBetween(DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,users.date_of_birth,CURDATE())'),array(Input::get('age_from'),Input::get('age_to')));
```